# How to use Request with query parameter in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I would like to get data from an e-commerce website. However, I can get products but no more than 24. The site is using page index query parameter. I am sending the query parameter but still, the script gets 24 products.

The code, result and the website -->  [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XXE2.jpg)

Code:

```
import requests
import sqlite3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

db = sqlite3.connect('veritabani.sqlite')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE products (id, product, price)")
url = 'https://www.trendyol.com/cep-telefonu-x-c103498'
html_text = requests.get(url,params={'q': 'pi:5'}).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
print(soup.contents)
products = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "p-card-wrppr"})
for product in products:
    product_id = product['data-id']
    product_name = product.find("div", {"class": "prdct-desc-cntnr-ttl-w two-line-text"}).find("span",{"class": "prdct-desc-cntnr-name"})["title"]
    price = product.find_all("div", {"class": "prc-box-sllng"})[0].text
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO products VALUES (?,?,?)", (product_id,product_name,price))
    print(product_id,product_name,price)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: Not clear: Do you mean you want the page size to be bigger, or that setting `pi` (page index?) you still get the first 25 results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website you have mentioned uses scroll pagination. But you still can get the data you want.

First of all, you are passing params wrong. Try to change this line

```
html_text = requests.get(url,params={'q': 'pi:5'}).text
```

with this:

```
html_text = requests.get(url,params={'pi':'5'}).text
```

And you will get 24 products on page number 5.
So basically, you can go like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    html_text = requests.get(url,params={'pi': str(i)}).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
    print(soup.contents)
    products = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "p-card-wrppr"})
    for product in products:
        product_id = product['data-id']
        product_name = product.find("div", {"class": "prdct-desc-cntnr-ttl-w two-line-text"}).find("span",{"class": "prdct-desc-cntnr-name"})["title"]
        price = product.find_all("div", {"class": "prc-box-sllng"})[0].text
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO products VALUES (?,?,?)", (product_id,product_name,price))
        print(product_id,product_name,price)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

This should get you products on 10 pages.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I understand the parameter part. But why should I use for loop?

Comment: If you want to iterate over many pages of the website in one execution of the script, then you have to use some loops

Comment: Now, I understand. It is like a page. Every 24 product different page index. So I give different numbers to the pi I always getting 24 products. Thanks a lot.